# Дизассемблирование кода в codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как дизассемблировать код в codeblocks?

Comment: Возможно всё ещё работает [такой способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620462/5812238): `ПКМ на строке` → `Run to Cursor`, затем `Debug->Debugging Windows->Disassembly`

Comment: Так открывается пустое (без кода) окно disassembly .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дебагер (gdb 8.0) из текущей поставки mingw-w64 (который *i686-7.1.0-release-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev2.7z*) при отладке С++ кода у меня зависает (при отладке С такого не наблюдается), возможно и у вас такая же проблема и поэтому окно Disassembly пустое.

Попробуйте поставить рядом более старую версию mingw-w64 и указать в настройках CodeBlocks чтобы он использовал gdb из той сборки.

Зайдите в настройки дебагера (*Меню - Settings - Debugger*), создайте новую конфигурацию (*GDB/CDB Debugger - Create config*) и укажите путь к нужному gdb.exe:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же, CodeBlocks может выводить ассемблерный код в двух форматах AT&T и Intel. Это настраивается тут же, в свойствах дебагера - *Choose diassembly flavor (GDB only)*.

После того, как вы добавили новый дебагер, вы можете переключаться между ними через *Меню - Debug - Active debuggers*.

---

Инструкция о том, как увидеть ассемблерный код:

- В качестве *Build target* выбрать *Debug*: *Меню - Build - Select target - Debug*
- Сделать *Rebuild* проекта: *Меню - Build - Rebuild* (`Ctrl`+`F11`)
- Если проект собрался успешно, поставить брекпоинт на строке кода и запустить отладку: *Меню - Debug - Start /Continue* (`F8`)
- После этого запустится дебагер и остановится на вашем брекпоинте. В этот момент и можно посмотреть дизассемблированный код: *Меню - Debug - Debugging windows - Disassembly*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, в логе на вкладке Debugger, будут примерно вот такие строчки:

```
Starting debugger: C:\dev\mingw-w64_5.3.0\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet -args B:/test/bin/Debug/test.exe 
done
Registered new type: wxString 
Registered new type: STL String 
Registered new type: STL Vector 
Setting breakpoints 
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10.1 
Child process PID: 4044 
At B:\test\main.cpp:7
```

Comment: zed я не профи С и С++ и простите за не компетентный вопрос. а возможно ли выполнить эту операция в windows?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов Этот ответ и есть про windows, и скриншоты оттуда же.

Comment: Где находится Build target? У меня нет жёлтого треугольника.

Comment: @Alex_ *Меню - Build - Select target - Debug*. Жёлтый треугольник является индикатором того, в каком конкретно месте остановлена программа. Если у вас он не появляется, значит программа не остановилась на брекпоинте.